# Отображение кириллицы в Code::Blocks

Tags: c++, кодировка, codeblocks

Написал для себя маленькую библиотеку для перевода кириллицы в латиницу и обратно. Соответственно, есть файл russianChar.cpp, в котором встречаются символы 'а', 'б', 'в' и пр.. Проблема в том, что при перезапуске Code::Blocks и открытии проекта эти символы читаются как символы другого алфавита, однако если открыть тот же файл в каком-нибудь Notepad++, то всё будет хорошо. Причём компилируется программа нормально, и вместо этих символов отображается кириллица. Как исправить? Сам пытался исправить это через Edit -> File Encoding, но я просто ломал символы тогда.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: потому что CodeBlock проявляет интеллект и включает кодировку windows-1252. А Вы похоже сохранили в Windows-1251. Переключите и все будет ок.

Comment: @KoVadim, а не подскажете где это сделать в C::B?

Comment: Setting->Editor, Там есть Default Encoding. Поставьте себе 1251 и переотройте документ. Но лучше конечно подумать и перебираться на utf-8. Хотя не факт, что это нормально в консоли виндовой будет.

Comment: К сожалению, это не помогло( При переоткрытии файла остаётся Windows-1252

Comment: к сожалению, я не могу залезть на Вашу машину и потыкать там настройки. Пробуйте сами.

Answer (score -1):

Решение оказалось достаточно простым. Чтобы избавиться от гениального "интеллекта" Code::Blocks, нужно в Settings -> Editor -> Encoding settings поменять галочку в Use this Encoding и нажать OK:[image: Решение проблемы] После переоткрытия документа всё будет в порядке.